# Degree of a map over a different ring in homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The degree of a map $f: S^n \to S^n$ is definied as the unique integer $H_n(f;\mathbb{Z} ): H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z})$ since $H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Now my question is if it's possible to take another ring, in particular $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, for example to determine if the degree $deg(f)$ is even or odd. To be more specific: Does the degree of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ relate in any way with the degree of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'd say no, because $H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z})$ is not isomorphic to $H_n(S^n;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. I'm not sure though, I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes; if $A \to B$ is any morphism of abelian groups then it induces a natural transformation $H_n(-, A) \to H_n(-, B)$, which implies that the map induced by $f$ on $H_n(-, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is the reduction $\bmod 2$ of the map induced on $H_n(-, \mathbb{Z})$.